# How to define the "R" in SIR model - removed or recovered?

Tags: epidemiology, compartmental-models, epidemic-curve

I have been trying to learn more about the `SIR` model since hearing about it due to recent events. In the process, I have heard various contradictory things. So I am seeking clarity. Specifically, I want to make sure I understand the `R` in `SIR` correctly. **Does `R` stand for [removed](https://pythonhosted.org/epydemic/sir.html) (ie, recovered or dead) or [recovered](https://medium.com/data-for-science/epidemic-modeling-101-or-why-your-covid19-exponential-fits-are-wrong-97aa50c55f8)?**

It is my understanding that `S` is for susceptible (percentage of living population not yet infected)  and `I` is for infected (percentage of contagious population).

Because the simplest `SIR` model implicitly assumes a recovered individual cannot transmit the virus (ie, immunity), I am inclined to think `R` has to be for removed to ensure that `S+I+R=1`; since the simplest `SIR` model does not account for population changes due to variable birth/death rates, I'm not sure that this equality relation holds. It follows that `dS/dt + dI/dt + dR/dt = 0 ==> dR/dt = - (dS/dt + dI/dt)`, which makes me wonder: what is the model actually capturing regarding `R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On regards of your question:

S: Susceptible (= N-confirmed cases)

I: Infected (= confirmed -recovered -deaths)

**R: Recovered / fatal (= recovered -deaths)**

For further reading:
https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/additional-examples/the-sir-epidemic-model/

Enjoy!